# Weird JSON appearance in cookie

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I tried to send json with a cookie from my express server and receive it from my client side js.

So it went pretty well at the server side. This is how the stringified json looks like on the server side.

[image: This is how the stringified json looks like on the server side.]

But it became so weird at the client side. This is how the json looks like on the client side.

[image: This is how the json looks like on the client side.]

Comment: Cookies are URL-encoded because there are some character that aren't allowed in them.

Comment: @Grumpy Use `decodeURIComponent()` to decode it.

Comment: @Barmar Youre right, i removed the comment.